# Merge sets in dictionary of sets if they contain the same element

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge, set

I have a dictionary of sets looking like this:

```
dictionary = {'0':{'apple','pear','banana'},'1':{'orange', 'apple'},'2':{'grape'}, '3': {'banana','peach'}
```

I would like to merge sets that have 1 or more of the same elements in the dictionary. Either keeping this dictionary or making a new one.

My goal is to have a dictionary like this:

```
dictionary = {'0':{'apple','pear','banana','orange','peach'},'1':{'grape'}}
```

The key names do not matter.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? And do the key names really matter so little that `'2': {'grape'}` can become `'1': {'grape'}` (if so, what's the point of the dictionary at all)?